# What are the differences between (varimax and promax) rotations in PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, matrix, factor-rotation

What are the differences between varimax and promax rotations in PCA?

Comment: @beathestar hmm, good question, I am not sure too. What I know is that if rotation happens, it is not PCA anymore because PCA is supposed to give you orthogonal components. Where did you find the question? FYI, your name is funny.